# Issue with C++ type casting

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, casting

I am trying to typecast a `float` to `unsigned char` using the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
        
    std::cout << int((unsigned char)((float)-10)) << "\n";
    std::cout << int((unsigned char)((float)300)) << "\n";
     
    return 0;
}
```

**gcc 12.1 output:**

```
0
255
```

which can be tried [here](https://godbolt.org/z/W7hra4eWj). It nicely clamps the values to `0` and `255`, and this is what I expect to get in any operating system. However, the problem occurs when I try the same code in Visual Studio 2022, which can be tried [here](https://godbolt.org/z/61aoox7ME).

**Visual Studio output**

```
246
44
```

It looks to me that `246` is actually `256-10` and the second output `44` is `300-256`. May I know why Visual Studio is producing a different result?

How can I make this simple casting cross-platform?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp

Comment: To me MSVS is the correct one here.  `-10` as an unsigned char should have the value of 246

Comment: Microsoft's documentation might help here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/conversions-from-floating-point-types. Specifically, converting from `float` to `unsigned char` involves an intermediate conversion to `long`.

Comment: Debug `unsigned char unCh = -10;` . And  the watch window: `246 'ö' unsigned char`.

Answer (score 10):

Floating-integral conversions [conv.fpint]

1. A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates;
   that is, the fractional part is discarded. **The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented
   in the destination type**.

Comment: I always forget about this caveat. +1